# Plone content allowed in specific folder

Tags: plone

I've created a custom type dexterity, in Plone 4.3.9, called PersonalPage that must be only allowed in a specific folder  **Members_folder/userfolder** .
In his FTI, by default `<property name="global_allow">False</property>`.
 The userfolder is created in Members_folder with the uid of the authenticated user, in Plone 4.3.3:

```
if homefolder is None:
        # create userfolder in members_folder
        members_folder.invokeFactory('Folder', user_id)
        userfolder = members_folder[user_id]
        utils = userfolder.plone_utils
        utils.changeOwnershipOf(userfolder, user_id,
                                        1, None)
        userfolder.setCreators([user_id])
        roles = list(userfolder.get_local_roles_for_userid(user_id))
        if 'Owner' not in roles:
            roles.append('Owner')
            userfolder.manage_setLocalRoles(user_id, roles)

        if shasattr(userfolder, 'canSetConstrainTypes'):
            userfolder.setConstrainTypesMode(1)
            defaultAllowedTypes = userfolder.getLocallyAllowedTypes()
            userfolder.setLocallyAllowedTypes(defaultAllowedTypes + ('personalpage',))    
            defaultAddableTypes = userfolder.getImmediatelyAddableTypes()
            userfolder.setImmediatelyAddableTypes(defaultAddableTypes + ('personalpage',))
        userfolder.reindexObjectSecurity()
        userfolder.reindexObject()
```

But after running this script the content type PersonalPage doesn't appear in the list of the addable and allowed contents types of the userfolder.
What's wrong with this? Is there another way to allowed a content type addable only for a folder?

Answer (score 4):

The script is not not working because of the global_allow flag.

Plone has 2 level of content type add restriction:

- The first one is a global settings: if a content type is not globally allowed it can't be added anywhere until a content type explicitly list it as a possible subtype
- The other one is the TTW addable types, that simply limits the set of contents defined above

If you need to limit addable types for a single folder you can define your folder as a new special type, used only once in the site (so keep global_allow true, create one folder, then disable it); finally specify PersonalPage as one of the allowed_types inside it and keep keep your global_allow settings for PersonalPage to False.

Alternatively you *can* use [collective.factorymenu](https://github.com/keul/collective.factorymenu), to modify Plone add menu through the web (is not released yet but is working).